# Why does my express router crash only when i send a JSON and not when i send a text ?

Tags: node.js, express

```
statusRouter.route('/')
.all(function(req,res,next){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  next();
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({
       name : "xyz"
     });
});
```

This crashes with - Header cant be set after it has been sent. 
But the catch is , this works :

```
statusRouter.route('/')
.all(function(req,res,next){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  next();
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.end("xyz");
});
```

NOTE : If I remove the writeHead function in the first case where I am sending JSON it starts working as well. Why does it not work when i do a writeHead on it ? This thing is driving me crazy can anyone explain why this happens ? 
P.S I'm working with express-generated app with my own router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `res.writeHead()` and `res.end()` are not implemented by Express, but by the Node.js [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module.

Its documentation states, for [`res.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback):

> If `data` is specified, it is equivalent to calling `response.write(data, encoding)` followed by `response.end(callback)`

So `res.end("xyz")` is short for:

```
res.write("xyz");
res.end();
```

For [`res.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) the documentation states:

> If this method is called and `response.writeHead()` has not been called, it will switch to implicit header mode and flush the implicit headers.

So `res.end("xyz")` is *actually* short for:

```
if (! res.headersSent) {
  res.writeHead(...);
}
res.write("xyz");
res.end();
```

This means that it's perfectly okay to issue `res.writeHead()` in your own code, before using `res.end()`. Internally, the `http` module will know that you already flushed the headers, so it won't do it again (therefore preventing the error you're getting). However, you can't set different headers, or change existing ones, once `writeHead()` has been called.

Now, `res.json()` is another matter: this isn't part of the `http` module, but of Express itself. Because it's used to send JSON responses, it will set the content type header to `application/json` (so you don't have to).

But this will only work if the headers haven't yet been sent already: you can't set headers when they have already been sent out. That's why you're getting the error.

If you want to set particular headers in Express, use [`res.set()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Express evaluates its routes in the order they are added. This means that the route handler passed to `.all()` will be executed first. In this handler, a response header is written and then `next()` tells Express to continue iterating its list of routes for another possible matching route.

It then matches the `.get()` route handler which tries to send a JSON response. However, `.json()` *implicitly sends a response header* as well as writes the value passed as JSON to the response and ends the response. This is why you are seeing an error about `writeHead()` being called more than once.

Comment: Thanks a lot it made sense